# Testing a method in Java

Tags: methods, program-entry-point

I'm a newbie.I'm trying to test my method in my Jgrasp compiler but it always gives errors.What am I missing here?Thanks.

```
   public class Assignment1a {
        public static void main(String[] args){
              System.out.println(twiceSum(5,10));
        }
   }

        public static int twiceSum(int x, int y){

                   int result = 2 * (x + y);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your error as well>>

Comment: Yes.Assignment1a.java:10: error: class, interface, or enum expected
 public static int twiceSum(int x, int y){
               ^
Assignment1a.java:16: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}    
^

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to `return` your method's result?

Also, seeing how you're coding in Java, shouldn't `twiceSum()` be a member of the `Assignment1a` class?

Comment: You're right.I failed to include twiceSum() as a member of Assignment1a class.Now it works.

Comment: That's good.  Unlike some other languages, Java doesn't really like free-floating methods like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can search these simple programs just by a simple google search.
Try to dig a bit before asking questions.

But as you are new, I am can tell you one of the error, is that you have given "int" as function signature, but you have not returned anything.

Try to add  a " return result;" statement at the end of twiceSum() function.

Post the error message, so that I can know the exact problem

Comment: I have much herder problems to work on,but I don't know how to test them.I was trying to learn how to do this using main method.